# Laravel 5 db:seed the username and password, but not authenticating on login

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I have implemented Database seeder to seed in user (default) credentials.

```
Admin::create(['name' => 'Super Admin', 'email' => 'admin@demo.in', 'password' => bcrypt('password') ]);
```

After running seed, I got success message. But when I try to make login, it says your credential are not matching. Is there any particular reason for this. Can't we seed user data with bcrypt??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we talk about the default `AuthController` of Laravel 5 obviously no you can't:

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

If you have a look at the `create()` function you can see that the data submitted as password is automatically bcrypted. So if you bcrypt the password too it is bcrypted a second time.

Comment: I'm not using the default user. I have created new admin, with the Entrust permissions. So, my create method for users is not in picture.

Comment: I did not say anything about a default *user*. I said if you use the default `AuthController`. Do you use the laravel AuthController or did you write your own AuthController. If you wrote your own then add its code to your question please.

Comment: Yes you are right Peh. I just checked the create method for Admin also. Thanks for sharing. I got the error.  I must not again decrypt the password. :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, some key points :

1. If you're using the User model for seeding, make sure that you'r not
   hashing the password twice that could happen if you have a mutator
   set in your model for the password column.
2. Be aware of your saved passwords in the browser, prefer writing
   explicitly your username and password (in this case).
3. Finally check if there is no typo in your username/email or password. (that was my case ‍♂️)

Comment: Thanks, in my case was the mutator, so twice the encript.,

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the data into my user table from my seeder as so:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
        'Email' => 'admin@QualityBooks.co.nz',
        'Name' => 'Administrator',
        'PhoneNumber' => '00000',
        'Password' => bcrypt('P@ssw0rd'),
        'isEnabled' => true,
        'isAdmin' => true
        ]);
```

This works for me and I am able to log in while using the default auth controller.